# how to use choices field in different way when creating model's object

Tags: django, django-models

i create a model with choises field

```
class Workers(models.Model):
      city_choice=(

                   ('1120','vegas'),
                   ('1104','newyork'),
                   ('1122','sandiego')

                  )

       BirthPlace=models.CharField(choices=city_choice,max_length=10)
```

in django shell i want to create model's object with city_name instead of  city_code

```
obj=Workers(BirthPlace='vegas')
obj.save()
```

but it's not work
how can i handel this program

Answer (score 2):

You could create a method or data structure that allows you to convert a choice label to a value.

```
class Workers(models.Model):
    city_choices = (
        ('1120','vegas'),
        ('1104','newyork'),
        ('1122','sandiego')
    )
    city_to_value = {city: value for value, city in city_choices}

    BirthPlace=models.CharField(choices=city_choice,max_length=10)
```

Now you can use this dictionary when creating your objects

```
Workers(BirthPlace=Workers.city_to_value['vegas'])
```